# How to group data based on a key and execute a function for each group using Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Given sample data:

```
data = [{"id": random.randint(1, 10), "content": random.choice(string.ascii_letters)} for _ in range(0, 1000)]
```

I want to group data entries by their `id` and execute a function e.g. `store_content(group)` on each group. For example, all entries with `id` 1 should be stored using `store_content`.

**Note** that each group of data might be very large, and I don't want to materialize/store them in memory when calling `store_content`.

How would I achieve this using PySpark?

A minimum example of what I tried:

```
import string
import tempfile
from random import randint, choice
from functools import partial

import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from more_itertools import peekable


def generate_samples(N):
  """ Generate data samples """
  return [{"id": randint(1, 10), 
          "content": choice(string.ascii_letters)} for _ in range(N)]



def save_content(partition, uri):
  """ Save each partition in a different folder """
  peeked_it = peekable(partition)
  key = peeked_it.peek(0)[0][0]
  values = next(peeked_it)
  
  with open(f"{uri}/{key}.txt", "w") as file:
      file.write("".join(values))


spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("test").getOrCreate()
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(generate_samples(1000)).map(lambda x: (x["id"], x))

with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tempdir:
  rdd = rdd.partitionBy(numPartitions=10).glom()
  rdd.foreachPartition(partial(save_content, uri=tempdir))
```

Stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 686, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 676, in process
    out_iter = func(split_index, iterator)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyspark/rdd.py", line 3472, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyspark/rdd.py", line 3472, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyspark/rdd.py", line 3472, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  [Previous line repeated 1 more time]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyspark/rdd.py", line 540, in func
    return f(iterator)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1178, in func
    r = f(it)
  File "<ipython-input-9-7e18b1132f02>", line 25, in save_content
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, tuple found
```

I expect to have e.g a file writen called `1.txt` with all characters that have the `id` 1.

Answer (score 0):

Just writing the file (without .glom()):

```
rdd.saveAsTextFile()
```

will results of a folder with N files, where N is your number of partitions. Then you can rename the file, if you are sure that your data is partionned as desired.

```
FileInfo(path='dbfs:/tmp/test5/part-00000', name='part-00000', size=0, modificationTime=1669214284000),
 FileInfo(path='dbfs:/tmp/test5/part-00001', name='part-00001', size=31, modificationTime=1669214284000),
 FileInfo(path='dbfs:/tmp/test5/part-00002', name='part-00002', size=93, modificationTime=1669214284000),
 FileInfo(path='dbfs:/tmp/test5/part-00003', name='part-00003', size=31, modificationTime=1669214284000),
 FileInfo(path='dbfs:/tmp/test5/part-00004', name='part-00004', size=0, modificationTime=1669214284000),
 FileInfo(path='dbfs:/tmp/test5/part-00005', name='part-00005', size=31, modificationTime=1669214284000),
 FileInfo(path='dbfs:/tmp/test5/part-00006', name='part-00006', size=31, modificationTime=1669214284000),
 FileInfo(path='dbfs:/tmp/test5/part-00007', name='part-00007', size=31, modificationTime=1669214284000),
 FileInfo(path='dbfs:/tmp/test5/part-00008', name='part-00008', size=31, modificationTime=1669214285000),
 FileInfo(path='dbfs:/tmp/test5/part-00009', name='part-00009', size=31, modificationTime=1669214285000)]

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("test").getOrCreate()
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(generate_samples(1000)).map(lambda x: (x["id"], x))
rdd = rdd.partitionBy(numPartitions=10).saveAsTextFile("temp.txt")
```